# Split string and fold in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to split a delimited string and then 'fold' the delimited parts such that the result is a string containing all possible 'paths'? I'm looking to purely use built-in functions if possible without resorting to recursive CTEs, etc.

This is a common functional pattern known as scan/fold. Wondering if T-SQL has a similar pattern.

Example

```
FOLD('A|B|C|D') = '[A],[A|B],[A|B|C],[A|B|C|D]'
```

EDIT: The order of the substrings must remain the same in the result. The target SQL version is Azure SQL.

Comment: Which version of  SQL-SERVER are you using ? from 2016 onwards we have `STRING_SPLIT()` function

Comment: You're going to need (want) `STRING_AGG`, and `STRING_SPLIT` is a problem here, @DigvijayS , as it still has no idea what Ordinal Position is.

Answer (score 2):

if you have sql-server-2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_SPLIT`

```
declare @text VARCHAR(MAX) ='A|B|C|D'

declare @result VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @result  = @result  + ',[' + STRING_AGG(X.value, '|') + ']' FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT(@text ,'|') X
    INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@text ,'|') Y
    ON X.value <= Y.Value
GROUP BY Y.Value

SET @result = STUFF(@result,1,1,'')

print @result
```

Result:

```
[A],[A|B],[A|B|C],[A|B|C|D]
```

Comment: Just be careful with `STRING_SPLIT`. As per the documentation *"The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."*

Comment: Thanks, this almost works but one caveat is that the result must be in the same order as it appears delimited. With your answer FOLD(A|C|B|D|E) -> [A],[A|B],[A|C|B],[A|C|B|D],[A|C|B|D|E]. It should be [A],[A|C],[A|C|B],[A|C|B|D],[A|C|B|D|E]. I have added the missed requirement, apologies.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall that example isn't the same as that in your question. Based on  the sample you did give us, it *seemed* **safe** to assume that characters were in alphabetical order.

Comment: it is a quick and dirty solution and it's the only advantage is using built-in functions. As @Larnu mentioned, it is not guaranteed ordered result.

Answer (score 2):

As I note in the comments, `STRING_SPLIT` has a big caveat in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.

As a result, you're safer off using a function that gives you the ordinal position. In this case I use [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) and then *assume* you are using  SQL Server 2017+:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(20) = 'A|B|C|D';
WITH Splits AS(
    SELECT DS.ItemNumber,
           DS.Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@YourString,'|') DS),
Groups AS(
    SELECT S1.ItemNumber,
           CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG(S2.Item,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S2.ItemNumber),']') AS Agg
    FROM Splits S1
         JOIN Splits S2 ON S1.ItemNumber >= S2.ItemNumber
    GROUP BY S1.ItemNumber)
SELECT STRING_AGG(Agg,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ItemNumber)
FROM Groups;
```

If you aren't on SQL Server 2017+, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69b55af65ed6a7ddfbbb9735d6b496fa)

Comment: Thanks. My target SQL version is Azure SQL.

Comment: Then you have access to `STRING_AGG` @DavidJamesBall .

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't want (or can't use) that **SUPER** `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`, here is an XML approach that will maintain the sequence

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'A|B|C|D'

;with cte as (
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
), cte1 as (
   Select *
         ,Comb ='['+stuff((select '|' +RetVal From cte Where RetSeq<=A.RetSeq Order By RetSeq For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') +']'
    From  cte A
    Group By RetSeq,RetVal
)
Select NewValue = stuff((select ',' +Comb From cte1 Order By RetSeq For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
[A],[A|B],[A|B|C],[A|B|C|D]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with v2016 there is JSON, which allows for a *position-safe* splitter using a JSON array. The path can be built with a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @yourString VARCHAR(MAX) ='A|B|C|D';

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT A.[key] AS ItmIndex
          ,A.[value] AS ItmVal 
    FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(@yourString,'|','","'),'"]')) A
)
,rcte AS
(
    SELECT ItmIndex, ItmVal
          ,CAST(ItmVal AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Result 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE ItmIndex=0

    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.ItmIndex, cte.ItmVal 
          ,CAST(CONCAT(rcte.Result,'|',cte.ItmVal) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM cte
    INNER JOIN rcte ON cte.ItmIndex=rcte.ItmIndex+1
)
SELECT * FROM rcte;
```

The idea in short:

- The first cte will transform your string into a set with a guaranteed sort order (other than `STRING_SPLIT()`).
- The second cte will start with the array's index 0 and then travers the list adding each item to the growing string.